# google admin sdk drive audit report api gives empty result

Tags: google-drive-api, google-admin-sdk

Referring below doc , have added audit scope to the client access.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive

New Scope : admin.reports.audit.readonly

Over google oauthplayground , we r getting empty result so far

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 112
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
Content-location: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Expires: Mon, 08 Sep 2014 05:49:14 GMT
Server: GSE
Etag: "xyz"
Cache-control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
Date: Mon, 08 Sep 2014 05:49:14 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{ "kind": "admin#reports#activities", "etag": "\"xyz\"" }
```

Same result if i pass user email id instead of all

Am i missing something here.Any other config need to be enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your full HTTP request call?  I made the following few calls, and it is all successful with results.

1)  Retrieve all users google drive events
GET
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive

2) Retrieve just one user google drive events
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/myuser@myuserdomain.com/applications/drive

One thing to keep in mind is that these [Drive Activity reports](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive) are ONLY available to Google for App Unlimited version.

"The Google Drive activity report report may be used only for lawful purposes in accordance with your Customer Agreement. These reports apply to Google Apps Unlimited accounts."

If you have not purchased the unlimited version, I don't think the reports will be available for you to be retrieved.

note: the [docs activity API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-docs) is available to Google Apps for Business and Education accounts

Comment: Thnx Emily , i we do a recheck n confirm if thats the case.

Comment: Emily , issue was about the account type not being unlimited.With an unlimited account i was able to fetch result.Docs activity api is deprecated n will be shut down by Jan 2015, so cant rely on that.Thnx a lot for ur answer.